# how to get parameter method from array

Tags: android

I have method to resize image and I want to get the parameter from array, but it keeps showing error says

```
incompatible types 
found int 
required android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
```

this is my method

```
public Drawable ResizeImage (int imgResize){
        Display imgPost = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        double dvcWidth = imgPost.getWidth();

        BitmapDrawable imgBD = (BitmapDrawable)this.getResources().getDrawable(imgResize);
        double imgHeight = imgBD.getBitmap().getHeight();
        double imgWidth = imgBD.getBitmap().getWidth();

        double imgRatio = dvcWidth/imgWidth;
        int newImgHeight = (int) (imgHeight*imgRatio);

        Bitmap imgBmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),imgResize);
        Drawable imgDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(this.getResources(),getResizedBitmap(imgBmap,newImgHeight,(int) dvcWidth));

        return imgDrawable;
    }
```

my array

```
int[] imgDvc= new int[]{
            ResizeImage(R.drawable.pc),
            R.drawable.ps4,
            R.drawable.xbone
}
```

and I call my array through here

```
List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
         for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
        hm.put("Dvc", Integer.toString(imgDvc[i]) );
        aList.add(hm);
    }
String[] game= {"Dvc"};
```

i use it for fill listview, thank you for the answer(s).

Comment: To which line in the code is the error referring to?

Comment: @MehmetKologlu this  ResizeImage(R.drawable.pc) line.

Comment: Oh i see it now. You've declared an int array, yet youre trying to put a `Drawable` into it. You cant do that.

Comment: @MehmetKologlu actually, i've tried some type data but it kept showing error, what type data shoud i use for my drawable method.

Comment: It's not your method that's the problem it's your design. You cannot put a `Drawable` inside an `int` array. On the other hand, you cannot make your method return an `int` (resource ID). You should come up with another approach. I don't know what you use that array for so I cant really help there.

Comment: @MehmetKologlu I use the array to fill listview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just going to put 3 images just use 3 image views and scale one to resize

Comment: i can't do that from imageview, the images have about 800x600, it would slow down the device. i want to resize it through java.

Comment: Loading a bitmap into the memory is not a fast approach. (and that is exactly what decodeBitmap does) I'm very confident that just using the XML attribute scaleX and scaleY of an imageView will be faster

Comment: Also 800x600 is not even a large image.

Comment: You can also use a library like Fresco if youre concerned about image loading efficiency